# Executing .js file on ubuntu 14.04 VPS error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

Hello when I try to run my sell.js javascript on ubuntu I get this error:

> node sell.js

```
socket timed out
socket closed
connecting to 72.165.61.175:27018
connected
encrypt request

/var/www/bot/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:150
  var cryptedSessKey = require('crypto').publicEncrypt(fs.readFileSync(__dirna
                                         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'publicEncrypt'
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/var/www/bot/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:150:42)
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (/var/www/bot/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:106:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Connection._readPacket (/var/www/bot/node_modules/steam/lib/connection.js:50:8)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
    at Connection.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

code in the /var/www/bot/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:

```
handlers[EMsg.ChannelEncryptRequest] = function(data) {
  this._connection.setTimeout(0);

  this.emit('debug', 'encrypt request');

  this._tempSessionKey = require('crypto').randomBytes(32);
  var cryptedSessKey = require('crypto').publicEncrypt(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.pub'), this._tempSessionKey);
  var keyCrc = require('buffer-crc32').signed(cryptedSessKey);

  var encResp = new schema.MsgChannelEncryptResponse().encode();
  var body = new ByteBuffer(encResp.limit + 128 + 4 + 4, ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

  body.append(encResp);
  body.append(cryptedSessKey);
  body.writeInt32(keyCrc);
  body.writeUint32(0);

  this._send(EMsg.ChannelEncryptResponse, body.flip());
};
```

I did npm install --save crypto but it doesnt work i'm always getting this error.. please if someone know how to fix this let me know.

Comment: do you already install build-essentials in ubuntu? Some NPM packages needs these to compile the dependencies.

Comment: @manuerumx i installed it now tryed to run the script again but same error..

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Be aware, if you installed node from ubuntu repository, you have the old version 0.10 or 0.12 Those versions don't have the crypto.publicEncrypt function. You need to upgrade to branchs 4.x or 5.x and to do that, you need to install manually node.js

Comment: @manuerumx seems like the version of node was the problem i had 0.10 thanks for that you can make answer and i will rate it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback and testing, the problem is currently Ubuntu 14.04 repositories have the Node 0.10 branch. In this branch, crypto.publicEncrypt API function does not exist. You have to install versions 4.x or 5.x node.js to make use of these functions.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

For Node.js v4:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Alternatively, for Node.js v5:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Optional**: install build tools

To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```